# Got error while installing module in magento2 'SQLSTATE [HY000] [2000] No such file or directory'

Tags: magento2

I Created module in magento 2. 
Trying to install created module by use of command - ' sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade ' and i got following error.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to resolve this issue is:

get error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

solution: create symlink from mamp mysql.sock to /tmp/mysql.sock

ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock

The cause of my case is Mamp install mysql and socket in other directory and Magento 2 looking mysql.sock in default place. So we just need to link the default place to Mamp place. This will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think this error happens when your command line php does not communicate with the database.

Check which php are you using in command line by typing `which php`. Is it the same one used by your server? If not make sure you export it in your bash profile. For example the mamp php on mac:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin:$PATH
```

Also check that the command line is using the right mysql where your database is stored. If you login into mysql via terminal:

1) does the db exist there?

2) does the user have enough privileges?

Also you can append the command with `-v, --v, or ---v` to see more detailed messages.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/app/etc/env.php` and change:

```
'host' => 'localhost',
```

to:

```
'host' => '127.0.0.1',
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update your right IP address and host name to the host configuration file

I am using fedora 23 my configuration file located in /etc/hosts

command for edit configuration

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

then add the below line or edit your old configuration

```
<ip-address> <host name>
```

for example **192.168.1.8  bu.gworks.mobi**